# PHPUnit Cannot acquire reference to $GLOBALS

Tags: php, phpunit, github-actions

I am getting an error when running PHPUnit tests on GitHub actions.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot acquire reference to $GLOBALS in /home/runner/work/project-name/project-name/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Configuration.php on line 570
```

It seems like this error is likely related to PHP8 (https://php.watch/versions/8.1/GLOBALS-restrictions), but the test matrix should only be running PHP 7.2 and 7.4 (tests run fine locally on PHP 7.4).

Error shown here in [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/devinsays/woocommerce-coupon-restrictions/runs/4611622660?check_suite_focus=true). [Testing matrix is here](https://github.com/devinsays/woocommerce-coupon-restrictions/blob/master/.github/workflows/php-tests.yml).

Any help much appreciated!

--

Edit:

Resolved this by specifically setting the PHP Version in the container as the first step:

```
# PHPUnit errors with latest PHP 8.X build.
# This specifically sets PHP version to 7.4.
- name: Setup PHP with tools
uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
with:
    php-version: '7.4'
    tools: phpunit
```

Answer (score 17):

You are using PHPUnit 7.5.20 which is [not compatible](https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html) with PHP 8.

Answer (score 13):

Had the same error when running a CI job on PHP 8.1 with Composer installation on `--prefer-lowest` with phpunit version 8.5.12

Bumping the `phpunit/phpunit` dependency from `>=8.5` to `>=8.5.23` did resolve this issue.

Comment: ^8.5.14 was in my case the version which seems to solve the problem